# How can I change the CONFIG_ARCH_OPTIONAL_KERNEL_RWX value? by changing arch/Kconfig file directly?

Tags: linux, build, linux-kernel, arm, kbuild

I had asked a quesion at kernelnewbies email list and later I thought I found the answer (I thought I can put it in my defconfig). But then later found it was my mistake. So I still have the question and I ask it here to get answer.
This is what I see when I search “KERNEL_RWX” during “make menuconfig” for arm64 kernel(5-10.0-rc5).
The Kconfig file says CONFIG_STRICT_KERNEL_RWX is for setting text and rodata read-only.

```
 Symbol: ARCH_OPTIONAL_KERNEL_RWX [=n]   
 Type  : bool   
 Defined at arch/Kconfig:928   

 Symbol: ARCH_OPTIONAL_KERNEL_RWX_DEFAULT [=n]   
 Type  : bool   
 Defined at arch/Kconfig:931   

 Symbol: STRICT_KERNEL_RWX [=y]   
 Type  : bool   
 Defined at arch/Kconfig:937   
   Prompt: Make kernel text and rodata read-only   
   Depends on: ARCH_HAS_STRICT_KERNEL_RWX [=y]   
   Visible if: ARCH_HAS_STRICT_KERNEL_RWX [=y] && ARCH_OPTIONAL_KERNEL_RWX [=n]   
   Location:   
 (1) -> General architecture-dependent options
```

I wanted to try setting STRICT_KERNEL_RWX to =n. The 'Visible if' descriptionn says this option is visible when ARCH_OPTIONAL_KERNEL_RWX is =y which is now =n. (The STRICT_KERNEL_RWX menu didn't appear as a configurable menu in the menuconfig at this time). This is the lines in arch/Kconfig.

```
config ARCH_OPTIONAL_KERNEL_RWX
    def_bool n
```

So I modified to ARCH_OPTIONAL_KERNEL_RWX=y in arch/Kconfig line 928. (BTW, This is question : is it correct to modify this Kconfig file directly? I’m not sure at the moment)
Then I could see the STRICT_KERNEL_RWX menu in the menuconfig and I set it to =n as I wanted.
But when I build the kernel, I see this errors.

```
ckim@ckim-ubuntu:~/ProjX/LinuxDevDrv/kernel-release-RD-INFRA-2020.11.30$ makeit
  CALL    scripts/atomic/check-atomics.sh
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  CC      arch/arm64/mm/mmu.o
arch/arm64/mm/mmu.c: In function 'parse_rodata':
arch/arm64/mm/mmu.c:595:28: error: 'rodata_enabled' undeclared (first use in this function)
  595 |  int ret = strtobool(arg, &rodata_enabled);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
arch/arm64/mm/mmu.c:595:28: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
arch/arm64/mm/mmu.c: In function 'map_entry_trampoline':
arch/arm64/mm/mmu.c:614:18: error: 'rodata_enabled' undeclared (first use in this function)
  614 |  pgprot_t prot = rodata_enabled ? PAGE_KERNEL_ROX : PAGE_KERNEL_EXEC;
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
arch/arm64/mm/mmu.c: In function 'map_kernel':
arch/arm64/mm/mmu.c:669:23: error: 'rodata_enabled' undeclared (first use in this function)
  669 |  pgprot_t text_prot = rodata_enabled ? PAGE_KERNEL_ROX : PAGE_KERNEL_EXEC;
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:283: arch/arm64/mm/mmu.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:500: arch/arm64/mm] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:1799: arch/arm64] Error 2
```

variable “rodata_enabled” is defined in init/main.c as below.

```
#if defined(CONFIG_STRICT_KERNEL_RWX) || defined(CONFIG_STRICT_MODULE_RWX)
bool rodata_enabled __ro_after_init = true;
static int __init set_debug_rodata(char *str)
{
    return strtobool(str, &rodata_enabled);
}
__setup("rodata=", set_debug_rodata);
#endif
```

But now that CONFIG_STRICT_KERNEL_RWX=n, the above lines are not compiled here (CONFIG_STRICT_MODULE_RWX=n too). However, arch/arm64/mm/mmu.c code is still using `rodata_enabled`. Is this a bug of the code? Or am I missing something?

I can modify init/main.c and include/linux/init.h so that this rodata_enabled and related functions be defined regardless of these CONFIG values and make the errors go away, but I’m curious if this a kind of kernel bug raising compiler error.
So again my question is how should I change ARCH_OPTIONAL_KERNEL_RWX value? I tried setting it in my defconfig file but when I do `make xxx_defonfig`, the .config file shows still ARCH_OPTIONAL_KERNEL_RWX=n. Should I edit the arch/Kconfig file really?

Comment: You modify kernel configuration for a particular build either by editing `.config` or by using the configuration tools like `make menuconfig`, not by editing the Kconfig files.

Comment: Yeah, but if I change CONFIG_STRICT_KERNEL_RWX=n in .config, it goes back to CONFIG_STRICT_KERNEL_RWX=y when I build the kernel again.

Comment: If the option is set to not be available there is probably a good reason for that. This configuration is then probably not supported on the architecture.

Comment: Options that do not have a prompt are not meant to be changed by the user. They may be turned on by a `select` line in the Kconfig.

Comment: By the way, `CONFIG_SOME_OPTION=n` is not a valid setting in the ".config" file. Options are set to `n` by removing them or commenting them out.

Comment: I wouldn't class the undeclared `rodata_enabled` as a bug because it only occurs in unsupported configurations. Once you start modifying kernel source code files (such as "arch/Kconfig") then you may need to change other files (such as "arch/arm64/mm/mmu.c" and "include/linux/init.h") as a consequence. In this case, it would be necessary to add an `#if defined(CONFIG_STRICT_KERNEL_RWX) || defined(CONFIG_STRICT_MODULE_RWX)` `#endif` wrapper around the `parse_rodata` function definition.

Comment: By the way, it would be safer to modify "arch/arm64/Kconfig" rather than "arch/Kconfig", for example by adding `select ARCH_OPTIONAL_KERNEL_RWX` and `select ARCH_OPTIONAL_KERNEL_RWX_DEFAULT` under `config ARM64`. You will still have the other consequential source code changes to deal with.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks, I understand what you said (including `select` by modifying Kconfg). I'm almost sure I shouldn't be chaning Kconfig though (and the consequential source change). I was just curious.

Comment: @ChanKim Well modifying the Kconfig files does put you into "modified kernel source" territory. There is nothing to stop you modifying the kernel sources for private use, but if you distribute the kernel binaries you need to make the modified sources (or at least a kernel patch) available under the terms of the GPL. (If it is a useful change, you could even consider submitting it for inclusion in the mainline kernel sources.)